# How to replace all the empty cells as 0 value for numeric and as Nil for categorical values in R?

Tags: r, replace

I am learning R and I came across a problem regarding to replace all the empty cells as **0** value for **numeric** and as **Nil** for **categorical** values.
Here is the sample input,

```
Name  data_1 
 a     2
 b     3
       5
 d     
 e     8
```

I am trying to get output like this in R,

```
Name  data_1 
 a     2
 b     3
 Nill  5
 d     0
 e     8
```

I dont know how to replace empty cells as 0 for numeric and Nil for categorical columns.

Comment: Do you have empty cells as in `""` or `NA` ?  If it is the former, both the columns are `character` or `factor` class (which seems unlikely) given that `read.csv/read.table` converts the empty to `NA` elements

Comment: I have empty cells as "" .

Comment: Please check the `str(yourdataset)` whether you have `character` or `factor` class columns?

Comment: Try `df1[] <- lapply(df1, function(x) if(all(grepl("^([0-9]+|)$", x))) as.numeric(replace(x, x=="", "0")) else replace(x, x=="", "Nill"))`

Comment: Its factor class column.

Comment: If it is factor class then convert to character first i.e. `df1[] <- lapply(df1, as.character)` and then use the code in the previous line

Comment: Its working , but for numeric values its replacing as NA rather than 0. So after that  do i need to insert this code.df1[df1 == " NA"]  <- 0

Comment: I tried it on an example data and it is working for me i.e. `df1 <- structure(list(Name = structure(c(2L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 5L), .Label = c("", 
"a", "b", "d", "e"), class = "factor"), data_1 = structure(c(2L, 
3L, 4L, 1L, 5L), .Label = c("", "2", "3", "5", "8"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("Name", 
"data_1"), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = "data.frame"); df1[] <- lapply(df1, as.character);
df1[] <- lapply(df1, function(x) if(all(grepl("^([0-9]+|)$", x))) as.numeric(replace(x, x=="", "0")) else replace(x, x=="", "Nill"))`

Comment: In my case its giving Nill value only for numeric column too, but if i use the code you provided above its working fine.

Comment: It is based on what you said that both the columns are `factor` class and for me it is giving the expected output you showed i.e. `df1
#  Name data_1
1    a      2
2    b      3
3 Nill      5
4    d      0
5    e      8`